# How to solve the following congruence $2^{59}(59!) \equiv x\pmod{61}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$$2^{59}(59!) \equiv x\pmod{61}$$

Have no idea on how to proceed, I dont know how to use Fermat's little theorem (if it has to be used, I have no idea about how to do it). Can someone help me on the solution of even on what I should study to solve by myself? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: multiply both sides by $2\cdot60$ and use Fermat's little theorem and Wilson's theorem.

Comment: Or algorithms:  *Mathematica*:  `QuotientRemainder[2^59 59!, 61][[2]]` $31$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you multiply both sides by $60$, you obtain $2^{59}\cdot 60!\equiv 60x\mod 61$. Notice that $$60!\equiv -1\mod 61$$ (this follows from $(p-1)!\equiv -1\mod p$ for primes $p$; do you see why?), so that you get
$$-2^{59}\equiv 60x\mod 61.$$

Next, multiply both sides by $2$, so that you obtain
$$-2^{60}\equiv 120x\mod 61.$$

Which result now tells you that $2^{60}\equiv 1\mod 61$?

It thus remains to find the inverse of $120$ modulo $61$ to obtain $x$.

Comment: Mate, isn't $7!$ divisible by $8$? Or does $p$ have to be prime?

Comment: @NεoPλατo $p$ must be prime, thanks.

Comment: The reason being:  any composite can get all it's prime factors being in the multiplication, prior to some point before it's highest prime power factor.

Comment: It's called Wilson's Theorem.  If $p$ is prime then $(p-1)! \equiv -1\pmod p$.    However if $p$ is not prime then $(p-1)! \equiv 0 \pmod p$.